# How to get dependable drop down using web api in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my html code

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
<select ng-change="getData(currentSelected)" class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection as selection for selection in data">
        <option value="" selected>Select the bankname</option>
       </select>
<select ng-change="getData(currentSelectedstate)"  class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelectedstate" ng-options="my.state as my.state for my in newdata">
            <option value="" selected>Select the state</option>
        </select>
<select ng-change="getData1(currentSelecteddistrict)"  class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelecteddistrict" ng-options="my.district as my.district for my in data1">
  <option value="" selected>Select the district</option>
        </select>
 </body>
```

And my js code is

```
 var app=angular.module("mainApp",[]);
   app.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$http",function ($scope,$http){
     $http.get("company.in/ifsc/banklist").then(function(response){
        $scope.data=response.data[0].data;
     });

       $scope.getData = function(name){

         $http.get("company.in/ifsc/state/" +name).then(function(response) {
          $scope.newdata = response.data;

        });
       }

     $scope.getData1= function(name1){

         $http.get("company.in/ifsc/district/""+name+", +name1).then(function(response) {
          $scope.data1 = response.newdata;
     });
       }
    }]);
```

First two api are working fine, When i select particular state in second drop down its not taking the value , How to append fetched bankname and state to the third api? so that i get the list of district in the third drop down.... , can anyone please help?

Comment: **$scope.getData** same scope variable name used is there any reason behind this?

Comment: There is probably an error in this API call: `$http.get("company.in/ifsc/district/"+name+, +name1)`

Comment: just console your response of third request and check whether it is proper or not

Comment: To get  district you are using *name* and *name1* but you have not pass name variable in function , so this will cause error and also check your result in console.

Comment: I tried its not working @Mistalis

Comment: can anyone please help?